# converting all elements of a list into a factor

Tags: r, random-forest

I have created 10 samples out of the training data set. I have trained random forest models using these 10 samples. I would like to test these models on the test set and obtain 10 predicted dataset.However, when I want to change the predicted probabilities into yes/no classes, I get merely one large factor instead of a list of factor.

```
# Training models

set.seed(111)
sample_num = 10
modelList<- vector("list", sample_num)
names(modelList)<-sprintf("model%s", seq(1:sample_num))

for(s in 1:sample_num){
trainingdata<-CVD_trainingSamples[[s]]
modelList[[s]] <- randomForest(death ~., data = trainingdata, 
ntree = 500)
}

# Test the trained models on the control set

predictControl<-vector("list", sample_num)
names(predictControl)<-sprintf("prediction of model%s", 
seq(1:sample_num))

for(s in 1:sample_num){
fitModel<-modelList[[s]] 
predictControl[[s]]<- predict(fitModel, controlBatch, type = 
"prob")[,2]
}

for(s in 1:training_num){
predClass_control <- vector("list", training_num)
predClass_control<- 
as.factor(ifelse(predictControl[[s]]>0.5,1,0))
}
```

the result of predClass_control is a large factor (9670 elements) while I expect it to be a list of length 10, each element containing 9670 factors

Answer (score 0):

In this part of code
for(s in 1:training_num){

```
predClass_control <- vector("list", training_num)
predClass_control<- 
as.factor(ifelse(predictControl[[s]]>0.5,1,0))
}
```

you reassign the variable `predClass_control` so its value is dropped at every iteration of for loop.